# How to unproxy bytebuddy proxy in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, byte-buddy

I used Javassist in my hibernate-based project a while ago, and in a place in the code where I needed the real instance of the proxy, I simply did this:

```
Object unproxiedEntity = Hibernate.unproxy(proxy);
```

Now I have switched to ByteBuddy and I wish to do the same thing. However, the Hibernate.unproxy() method does not work anymore since the proxy now is not implementing *HibernateProxy*, causing this segment of the code to return the proxy again. Apparently, the proxies generated with ByteBuddy is called *HibernateBasicProxy*. What can I do in order to get the real instance using ByteBuddy proxies?

Comment: This should just work; if it does not this is a bug. Have you posted this as a bug to Hibernate?

Comment: I think this is due to this being the same project as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51612784/methodhandler-in-hibernate-using-bytebuddy-proxies-gets-stuck-in-endless-loop
Basically I've been modifying the proxies in Hibernate, so it probably works in normal hibernate, but in my slightly modified version it does not. Strange however that the thing that broke it was changing the proxy implementation from Javassist to Bytebuddy.